# Variables and form data lost when Page_Load is run again after pressing button that calls method via OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am unfamiliar with C#/ASP/.NET (learning as I go), so it is very likely that I am going about this in an inferior way, in addition to the problems with my current way of doing this.  I will try to be as clear as possible (maybe overly so...).

I have a form with a textbox to take in a list of server hostnames, separated by line returns.  Upon pressing the submit button, it uses `PostBackUrl="~/btil_Info.aspx"`.  In btil_info.aspx.cs codebehind, I get the info from said textbox (hostnames_tb) from the previous form in `Page_Load()` using:

```
string hostnames = ((TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hostnames_tb")).Text;
```

Within Page_Load(), I loop through this list of hostnames and build a form containing several fields for each host (a few textboxes and a dropdown menu for each host).  After filling out these fields, upon pressing the Submit button here which calls Submit_Click() in the same codebehind, the page appears to reload because Page_Load is called again before Submit_Click() is executed.  In doing so, the the filled form data is lost and the list of hostnames is also lost.

At an earlier stage in development, I had this all on the very first form page, and the submit button didn't call `PostBackURL`, it simply called `Submit_Click()`, which worked perfectly fine.  The page didn't reload, the form stayed on the page, and I didn't lose data.  But as it is now, the button works the same way.  The only difference (that I see) being that this troublesome page is reached via the previous form calling `PostBackURL`.

I don't believe there's any point where anything should be requesting a page refresh/reload.  I don't actually care if the page refreshes/reloads as long as the form data is posted and as long as the list of hostnames from the previous form is also retrievable.  I just need to be able to access the form data and list of hostnames so that I can pass it to another method of mine that will update a SharePoint list (the code for that part is already working, though).  I tried making the `hostnames` string a class variable in the 2nd codebehind (btil_Info.aspx.cs) and setting it as soon as soon as the page loads if it is empty, but apparently it does not persist over the page reload and is set back to null.

Here's some snippets of code that I hope will be of some help:

First page, add_BTIL.aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="hostnames_tb" runat="server" Rows="20" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="225px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/btil_Info.aspx" Text="Submit" />
    <br />
    <asp:Literal ID="result" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    <br /><br />
    <textarea id="hostnames_textarea" cols="25" rows="20" name="hostnames" title="Hostnames"></textarea></div>
</form>
```

First page codebehind, add_BTIL.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hostnames = hostnames_tb.Text;
    /*
     * Etc.
     */
}
```

Second page, btil_Info.aspx:

```
<form id="hosts_form" runat="server">
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" Height="26px" UseSubmitBehavior="False" /><br />
        <asp:Literal ID="result" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
    </p>
    <br />
</form>
```

^ In this form, I read somewhere in my searches that `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` would prevent a page reload, but it did not help.  I didn't use it in my earlier version anyway, and did not have this issue.

Second page codebehind, btil_Info.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hostnames = ((TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hostnames_tb")).Text;
    // etc.....
}

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // etc.....
}
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're posting from add_BTIL.aspx to btil_Info.aspx then the Submit_Click function in file add_BTIL.aspx.cs will never be called.

Based on the limited markup you've given us for the btil_Info.aspx page...
If you aren't rendering your host names list inside of server controls inside the form id="hosts_form" then when you hit the submit button nothing is going to be posted to your Submit_Click function.

Personally I don't like post from one page to another so here are some suggestions below.

If you want to do a multi-page wizard then you might consider the asp.net [wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). 
Or if you want to keep it simple, use two asp [Panel controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and show the first one, post the data, and then hide the first and show the second one.

Comment: The markup I gave you for btil_Info.aspx is everything that is within the <body> tags, and there's nothing really outside of that (just !doctype/html/head/title tags).  And I gotta say I don't really like the posting between pages either.  I just felt that I may have been over my head jumping into this to begin with, so I stuck with a pretty simple form and posting data across pages instead of learning a Wizard or something.  I didn't actually know what controls would be applicable to do what I want, but your suggestions sound good and I will look into them.